# Merging on pairs of values in one column of each data frame

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I am trying to merge two data frames with columns of different lengths and rows.To give the exact idea DF1 is:

```
     ID     year    freq1   mun    
       1    2005    2     61137
       1    2006    1     61383
       2    2005    3     14520
       2    2006    2     14604
       4    2005    3     101423
       4    2006    1     102257
       6    2005    0     39039
       6    2006    1     39346
```

Whereas DF2 is:

```
      ID        year    freq2   mun
       1        2004    5     60857
       1        2005    3     61137
       2        2004    4     14278
       2        2005    4     14520
       3        2004    2     22563
       3        2005    0     22635
       4        2004    6     101015
       4        2005    4     101423
       5        2004    6     61152
       5        2005    3     61932
       6        2004    4     38456
       6        2005    3     39039
```

As you can see both year and mun variables are somewhat different and have only one common entry. So what I'm trying to achieve is to merge freq1 and freq2 columns with respect to ID's. However the trick is that DF1 should take priority (left merge?) in such way that year and mun variables are the ones chosen from DF1. **Desired output:**

```
      ID    year    freq1   mun    freq2
       1    2005    2     61137    5
       1    2006    1     61383    3
       2    2005    3     14520    4
       2    2006    2     14604    4
       4    2005    3     101423   6
       4    2006    1     102257   4
       6    2005    0     39039    4
       6    2006    1     39346    3
```

As well as other way around for DF2 taking priority in such way that:

```
      ID        year    freq2   mun   freq1
       1        2004    5     60857   2
       1        2005    3     61137   1
       2        2004    4     14278   3
       2        2005    4     14520   2
       3        2004    2     22563   0
       3        2005    0     22635   0
       4        2004    6     101015  3
       4        2005    4     101423  1
       5        2004    6     61152   0
       5        2005    3     61932   0
       6        2004    4     38456   0
       6        2005    3     39039   1
```

I've tried deleting year and mun columns and merge freq1 and freq2 according to common ID's however it only provides me with multiple duplicate entries. Any suggestions?

Comment: seems like,`dplyr::left_join(df1, df2)`.

Comment: I hope the new title better describes what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to match pairs of `ID`s in the data frames, in the order presented.

Matching on the `ID` column alone will cause a cross-product to be formed, giving four rows for `ID == 1`, which is what I assume you mean by "multiple duplicate entries."

To merge the pairs of `ID` values, you need to disambiguate the individual values, so the `merge` merges the first `ID` value in `df1` with the first `ID` value in `df2`, and similarly for the second `ID` values.

This disambiguation can be done by adding another column, which adds a counter for the number of `ID` values seen.  `seq_along` counts, and `ave` applies to the "levels" of `ID`:

```
df1$ID2 <- ave(df1$ID, df1$ID, FUN=seq_along)
df2$ID2 <- ave(df2$ID, df2$ID, FUN=seq_along)
```

Here's the new `df1`.  `df2` is similarly modified.

```
> df1
  ID year freq1    mun ID2
1  1 2005     2  61137   1
2  1 2006     1  61383   2
3  2 2005     3  14520   1
4  2 2006     2  14604   2
5  4 2005     3 101423   1
6  4 2006     1 102257   2
7  6 2005     0  39039   1
8  6 2006     1  39346   2
```

These are now appropriate for passing to `merge` to get the two sides that you want.  Removing the unused column from each side prevents the merge from taking data that you don't want:

```
> merge(df1, df2[-c(2,4)], by=c('ID', 'ID2'), all.x=T)[-2]
  ID year freq1    mun freq2
1  1 2005     2  61137     5
2  1 2006     1  61383     3
3  2 2005     3  14520     4
4  2 2006     2  14604     4
5  4 2005     3 101423     6
6  4 2006     1 102257     4
7  6 2005     0  39039     4
8  6 2006     1  39346     3
> merge(df1[-c(2,4)], df2, by=c('ID', 'ID2'), all.y=T)[-2]
   ID freq1 year freq2    mun
1   1     2 2004     5  60857
2   1     1 2005     3  61137
3   2     3 2004     4  14278
4   2     2 2005     4  14520
5   3    NA 2004     2  22563
6   3    NA 2005     0  22635
7   4     3 2004     6 101015
8   4     1 2005     4 101423
9   5    NA 2004     6  61152
10  5    NA 2005     3  61932
11  6     0 2004     4  38456
12  6     1 2005     3  39039
```

Note that `NA` values are used where there is no match.  You can replace these with `0` values if that is really appropriate.

The `[-2]` at the end removes the added column `ID2`.

This is a fairly unusual way to merge.  It depends on the order of the data in addition the values, so it does seem to be fragile.  But I do think that I've captured what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Yes! Works very nicely. I needed this to compare freq1 rates to corresponding freq2 rates of ID's, hence the unusual way of merging. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: an elegant technical solution _and_ a good explanation, incl. that this is an unusual merge that depends on certain assumptions about the data set.

Answer (score 2):

Use [*match*](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) function to find corresponding rows between DF1 and DF2. See the code below.

```
# Find rows in DF1 that matches rows in DF2, get "freq2" values from them. 
cbind(DF1, DF2[ match( DF1[,"year"], DF2[,"year"] ), "freq2" ])

# Find rows in DF1 that matches rows in DF2, get "freq2" values from them. 
cbind(DF2, DF1[ match( DF2[,"year"], DF1[,"year"] ), "freq1" ])
```

Comment: Unfortunately it tries to match year entries, which results in multiple NA values where years aren't equal.

Comment: What values do you want in such cases?